# Pandas Filter DF Column if Values are NaN or Anything else

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     a     b     c
0   dave   blue   NaN
1   bill   red    NaN
2   sally  green  Member
3   Ian    Org    Paid
```

How can I filter for rows that are EITHER `NaN` or have a value of "Member"?

Answer (score 2):

Yopu can chain 2 masks by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with `|` for bitwise `OR` and add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per row and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[(df.isna() | df.eq('Member')).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
       a      b       c
0   dave   blue     NaN
1   bill    red     NaN
2  sally  green  Member
```

Or you can replace value to missing values and then filter only missing rows:

```
df1 = df[df.replace('Member', np.nan).isna().any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
       a      b       c
0   dave   blue     NaN
1   bill    red     NaN
2  sally  green  Member
```